# PowerShell Result Array duplicates output

Tags: arrays, json, azure, powershell

I have created an if/else script that will output some results to an array and convert to JSON. I'm a bit confused as to why I get duplicate results when I run the script. Anyone have any ideas as to why?

My script:

```
$DynatraceTenantID = "asdf"
$DynatraceToken = "asdf"
$DynatraceServer = "asdf"

$TagName = "pmack"
$TagValue = "pmack"

$result_array_installed_already = @()
$result_array_installed_now = @()

$vms = Get-AzureRmResource -TagName $TagName -TagValue $TagValue | Where-Object {$_.ResourceType -like "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"}

Foreach ($vm in $vms) {
    $vm1 = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -Name $vm.Name
    $vm2 = $vm1.Extensions
    if ($vm2.Publisher -notcontains "dynatrace.ruxit"){
        Set-AzureRmVmExtension `
            -Name "Dynatrace" `
            -Publisher "dynatrace.ruxit" `
            -ResourceGroupName "$($vm1.ResourceGroupName)" `
            -Location "$($vm1.Location)" `
            -VMName "$($vm1.Name)" `
            -ExtensionType "oneAgentWindows" `
            -TypeHandlerVersion "2.3" `
            -Settings @{ "tenantId"=$DynatraceTenantID; "token"=$DynatraceToken;"server"=$DynatraceServer; }
        $objNow = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{
            VMaltered = $($vm1.Name)
            IDaltered = $($vm1.Id)
            }
        } else {
            $objAlready = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{
                VMinstalled = $($vm1.Name)
                IDinstalled = $($vm1.Id)
            }
        }

        $result_array_installed_already += $objAlready
        $result_array_installed_now += $objNow
    }

$result_array_installed_already | ConvertTo-Json

$result_array_installed_now | ConvertTo-Json
```

And the 1st run output shows as (note the 'pmackVM' name is duplicated):

```
RequestId IsSuccessStatusCode StatusCode ReasonPhrase
--------- ------------------- ---------- ------------
                         True         OK OK          
[
    {
        "IDinstalled":  "/subscriptions/1221df0b-8a2e-45b3-b750-9ef61575087d/resourceGroups/pmack-container/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/pmackVM",
        "VMinstalled":  "pmackVM"
    },
    {
        "IDinstalled":  "/subscriptions/1221df0b-8a2e-45b3-b750-9ef61575087d/resourceGroups/pmack-container/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/pmackVM",
        "VMinstalled":  "pmackVM"
    }
]
{
    "IDaltered":  "/subscriptions/1221df0b-8a2e-45b3-b750-9ef61575087d/resourceGroups/pmack-container/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/pmackVM1",
    "VMaltered":  "pmackVM1"
}
```

However, if I close and re-open PowerShell (to clear all the variables) and run it again, this is the output I receive:

```
[
    {
        "IDinstalled":  "/subscriptions/1221df0b-8a2e-45b3-b750-9ef61575087d/resourceGroups/pmack-container/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/pmackVM
",
        "VMinstalled":  "pmackVM"
    },
    {
        "IDinstalled":  "/subscriptions/1221df0b-8a2e-45b3-b750-9ef61575087d/resourceGroups/pmack-container/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/pmackVM
1",
        "VMinstalled":  "pmackVM1"
    }
]
```

Any ideas why the first one output would repeat itself? Please note, that I the first run was also on a fresh PowerShell session.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The repeated output comes from the fact that you are adding BOTH `$objAlready` and `$objNow` after the loop regardless of the IF condition. Add these objects to the resulting arrays INSIDE the `if` like this:

```
$DynatraceTenantID = "asdf"
$DynatraceToken = "asdf"
$DynatraceServer = "asdf"

$TagName = "pmack"
$TagValue = "pmack"

$result_array_installed_already = @()
$result_array_installed_now = @()

Foreach ($vm in $vms) {
    $vm1 = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -Name $vm.Name
    $vm2 = $vm1.Extensions
    if ($vm2.Publisher -notcontains "dynatrace.ruxit"){
        Set-AzureRmVmExtension `
            -Name "Dynatrace" `
            -Publisher "dynatrace.ruxit" `
            -ResourceGroupName "$($vm1.ResourceGroupName)" `
            -Location "$($vm1.Location)" `
            -VMName "$($vm1.Name)" `
            -ExtensionType "oneAgentWindows" `
            -TypeHandlerVersion "2.3" `
            -Settings @{ "tenantId"=$DynatraceTenantID; "token"=$DynatraceToken;"server"=$DynatraceServer; }

        $objNow = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{
            VMaltered = $($vm1.Name)
            IDaltered = $($vm1.Id)
        }
        $result_array_installed_now += $objNow
    } 
    else {
        $objAlready = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{
            VMinstalled = $($vm1.Name)
            IDinstalled = $($vm1.Id)
        }
        $result_array_installed_already += $objAlready
    }
}

$result_array_installed_already | ConvertTo-Json
$result_array_installed_now | ConvertTo-Json
```